# Merging models of multiple inputs

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer, conv-neural-network

I am having trouble merging 2 models of multiple inputs. The 2 models both receive multiple inputs for multichannel CNN. But it's giving me the error - `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` when I tried to merge them. Any idea what I am doing wrong here? Thank you very much for your assistance in advance.

```
def mergeCnnModel(cnnModel, cnnModel2):
    merged = concatenate([cnnModel.layers[-2].output, 
    cnnModel2.layers[-2].output])
    dense1 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(merged)
    outputs = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense1)
    model = Model(inputs=[cnnModel.input, cnnModel2.input], outputs=outputs)
    # compile
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    # summarize
    print(model.summary())
    return model
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the trace for the error?

Comment: Here's the trace

Comment: Can you try `Model(inputs=cnnModel.inputs+cnnModel2.inputs, outputs=outputs)`? The problem is passed model inputs.

Comment: It works, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting comment into answer: The problem is passing list of lists as inputs to the final model. You need concatenate the individual input lists of sub models:

```
model = Model(inputs=cnnModel.inputs+cnnModel2.inputs, outputs=outputs)
```